# Windows 8.1 Batch File Default App

Tags: batch, batch-file

I am making a batch file Contains this

```
@ECHO OFF
adb install %1
pause
exit
```

I want to make this batch File Default App for .apk files.Is Windows Send Parameters When You Open a file?If not Please Help For How to Make it.
(Sorry For Bad English)

Comment: What output from `assoc .apk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved problem by editing registry.In the Registry Enter the HKCR(Hkey Classes root) And edit file extension you want to edit.

Comment: You probably mean HKCR. File associations are stored in *HKey Classes Root*, not in *HKey Local Machine*.

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to convert your batch file to an executable .exe like this one [here](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php) Then you will need to right click on a .apk file and select open with. Then select choose default program. Then select choose another app on this pc. Then you should be able to find your bat file that you converted to an exe. Select the .exe you created.

Comment: I tried it but Doesn't work

Comment: what did not work

Comment: It doesn't open the .exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing next result from `assoc` and `ftype` commands:

```
==>assoc .apk
File association not found for extension .apk

==>ftype apkfile
File type 'apkfile' not found or no open command associated with it.

==>
```

and let full path to your batch is `"d:\bat\apkbatch.bat"`. Then you could write from *elevated* `cmd` window:

```
ftype apkFILE=%comspec% /D /C call "d:\bat\apkbatch.bat" "%1" %*
assoc .apk=apkFILE
```

Note that the *FileType* should always be created before making a *File Association*. **Resources**:

- [ftype: Display or change the link between a FileType and an executable program](http://ss64.com/nt/ftype.html);
- [assoc: Display or change the association between a file extension and a fileType](http://ss64.com/nt/assoc.html).